# Why is the same Speech Recognition code behaving differently every time i run?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webkitspeechrecognition

Here is my code

```js
export class recognition {
  constructor() { }

  public startrecognition() {
    const voice_recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    voice_recognition.continuous = false;
    voice_recognition.interimresults = false;
    voice_recognition.lang = "en-US";

    voice_recognition.start();

    voice_recognition.onresult = function (e) {
      const repsonse = e.results[0][0].transcript;
      this.cust_response(response);
      voice_recognition.stop();
    }

    voice_recognition.onerror = function (e) {
      voice_recognition.stop();
    }
  }

  public cust_response(response) {
    //Some code here using response given by customer//
  }
}
```

The problem here is I'm unable to call the `cust_response(response)` function from `voice_recognition.onresult`.

Edit:
I have changed this voice_recognition.onresult=function(event){} to voice_recognition.addEventListener("result",(event)=>{}) and this was calling the function inside it. But with this change it sometimes calling voice_recognition.addEventListener("result",(event)=>{}) and when i run again its not calling this function and even it's not executing voice_recognition.addEventListener("error",(event)=>{}). Why is the same code running sometimes and not running the other times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `function` keyword, you are not binding a context (`this`) to the function.

You should either:

- (preferred) Use an arrow function, which will bind the context
  Eg:

```
voice_recognition.onresult = (e) => {
  ...
  this.cust_response(response);
}
```

- Capture the `this` variable in the enclosing scope and refer to that
  Eg:

```
const self = this;

voice_recognition.onresult = function(e){
  ...
  self.cust_response(response);
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I have tried both individually and also combined....but none worked

Comment: Can you add any error messages you are getting in the console to your question? If you put a log statement at the start of the onresult callback do you see it?

Comment: please see the edit in the question. This time it was working but the same piece of code is behaving differently every time i restart code or refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use `bind(this)` or arrow function notation to access class member variables using `this` keyword in callbacks.

Try the following

```js
public startrecognition() {
  const voice_recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  voice_recognition.continuous = false;
  voice_recognition.interimresults = false;
  voice_recognition.lang = "en-US";

  voice_recognition.start();

  voice_recognition.onresult = (e) => {              // <-- arrow function
    const repsonse = e.results[0][0].transcript;
    this.cust_response(response);
    voice_recognition.stop();
  }

  voice_recognition.onerror = (e) => {
    voice_recognition.stop();
  }
}
```

You could refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/6513921) for more details.

Comment: i have tried using arrow function.But it was still not working

Comment: Then check if the `e.results[0][0].transcript` property is available in the `e` variable. Try to do `console.log(e)` at the top of the `onresult` callback.

Comment: How is the `startrecognition()` function called?

Comment: like just a normal function call. startrecognition()

Comment: So the `console.log` is triggered but the function `this.cust_response(response)` isn't called?

Comment: please see the edit in the question. This time it was working but the same piece of code is behaving differently every time i restart code or refresh the page